# Convert C++ map to c arrays - Performance

Tags: c++, c, stl

Is there a better way in terms of performance to convert a map imap  to char* array[] and integer array in C?

```
map<string, int> imap; // Code below will build the imap
....
....
....

char** carr;
int* iarr;

*carr = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*imap.size());
*iarr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*imap.size());

index = -1;
for(iter = imap.begin(); iter != imap.end(); ++iter)
{
    (*carr)[++index] = strdup(iter->first.c_str());
    (*iarr)[index] = iter->second;
}
```

-Kartlee

Comment: You are dereferencing too much. the assignments should be carr[++index] ="..." and iarr[index] = "...". Also, most people start indexes with zero and increment after usage. The lvalues at the malloc lines are also wrong.

Comment: You are  assuming that you can easily build something that works better than what the library author has written. Why should we believe that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't.  Just beautify your code a little. I guess a good compiler will optimise all the anomalies.

I would avoid calling c_str(), I would just create the array of STL string if possible, because that is the thing that uses up most time in your script.

Also side note: I myself place beautiful, understandable code before performance. Tidy your code and get rid of those ugly malocs. C++ supports NEW operator.

Comment: I can't use stl string as this need to be supported in C. Using new operator is okay as per your comment. Anyway thanks for the information that it can't be done in a better way and idioms.